# Redux and ReactJS Hooks: UseEffect Returns an Empty State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have this class component that returns state populated perfectly using Redux store:

```
class TopRatedComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchTopRatedMovies();
    }
    render() {

        const IMG_API_ROOT_LINK = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500';
        const { topRatedMovies, loading, error } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {loading && <div>LOADING...</div>}
                {error && <div>{error}</div>}
                <Container className="p-4" onScroll={this.onScroll}>

                    <div className="text-center">

                        {
                            topRatedMovies.results && topRatedMovies.results.map(topRated => (
                                <p>{topRated.title}</p>
                            ))
                        }
                    </div>

                </Container>

            </div>
        );
    }
}




const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const { topRatedMovies, loading, error } = state.topRatedMovies;
    return {
        topRatedMovies,
        loading,
        error
    };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {
        fetchTopRatedMovies
    }
)(TopRatedComponent);
```

However, when I switch the above class component into a functional component below so I can use ReactJS hooks with my code, but the state is always empty.

```
const TopRatedComponent = () => {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
      const [topRated, settopRated] = useState([]);

      useEffect(() => {
        settopRated(this.props.fetchTopRatedMovies)
     }, [this.props.fetchTopRatedMovies])
     
    
  const allState = useSelector((state) => state)
  console.log('CHOF: ' + JSON.stringify(allState));
  return (
    <div>
     WOOOOOOOW....
    </div>
  )
};
```

Comment: @yousaf it is coming from an action: import { fetchTopRatedMovies } from '../actions/topRatedAction.js';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't correctly transformed your class-based component into equivalent functional component.

Following are the problems in your functional component:

- In class component, you receive the `fetchTopRatedMovies` action creator as a prop and you dispatch it from the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. In functional component, you are not dispatching it.

  To dispatch the action in functional components, use [useDispatch()](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch) hook and use `useEffect` hook to dispatch this action after component has mounted.

  ```
  import React, { useEffect } from "react";
  import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

  const TopRatedComponent = () => {
     ...
     const dispatch = useDispatch();

     useEffect(() => {
         dispatch(fetchTopRatedMovies());
     }, []);

     ...
  };
  ```
- In class components, you access `props` object using `this` but in functional components, `props` object is passed as an argument. So, you can directly access it using the parameter name you use for the `props` object

  ```
  const TopRatedComponent = (props) => {
     console.log(props);
     // code
  };
  ```
- Data that your component receives as props from the redux store using `mapStateToProps` function and `connect` higher order component, can be accessed using [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) hook in functional components.

  ```
  import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

  const TopRatedComponent = () => {
      const { 
         topRatedMovies,
         loading,
         error
      } = useSelector(state => state.topRatedMovies);

      // code
  };
  ```

  **Note:** You can also use `connect` higher-order component and `mapStateToProps` to connect your functional component with the redux store.

For details of how to use hooks with `react-redux`, see: [react-redux - Hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#hooks)

Answer (score 1):

`this` doesn't work the same way in a functional component. You need to pull props from your function arguments instead.

```
const TopRatedComponent = (props) => {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
      const [topRated, settopRated] = useState([]);

      useEffect(() => {
        settopRated(props.fetchTopRatedMovies)
     }, [props.fetchTopRatedMovies])
     
    
  const allState = useSelector((state) => state)
  console.log('CHOF: ' + JSON.stringify(allState));
  return (
    <div>
     WOOOOOOOW....
    </div>
  )
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This actually work but still when I try to access topRated since that is where I store my object - and I have switched state initialization for top rated to object {} and I still get undefined. If I access state directly, I get my stuff logged out in the console log...

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions don't have their own context (`this` variable). I assume that `fetchTopRatedMovies` is an action (thunk) that fetches data from an API and set it to a global state. In this case, you need to also get that data using Redux hooks (if the version you are using supports it).

```
const TopRatedComponent = ({ fetchTopRatedMovies }) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    // this is written according to your `mapStateToProps` function.
    const { topRatedMovies, loading, error } = useSelector(({topRatedMovies}) => topRatedMovies);

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchTopRatedMovies();
    }, [fetchTopRatedMovies])
    
    if (loading) return 'LOADING...';
    if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>
     
    return (
      <div>
        etc...
      </div>
    )
};
```